# how to partitioning 2D array into smaller multiple 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, partitioning

let assume we have a 2D array with large dim like (65000 rows,14 col)
and we want to partition this array into multiple 2D arrays with no repetition depend on 1D array as position array(number of indexes)
how could I solve this problem

```
double[][] ch = new double[1000][14];


while(k<=dataset.length%100){
    int i=0;

    best = swarm.getBestPosition();
    ch = DatasetChunks(best, dataset, i++);
    ChunksPrint(ch, k);
    best=null;

    k++;
}
    
private static double[][] DatasetChunks(double[] best, double[][] dataset) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            ch1[i][j] = dataset[best[i]][j];
        }
    }
    return ch1;
}
```

Comment: *how could I solve this problem* The first step would be to clearly state the problem so that both you and I might understand it.  You have a sample input array of [1000][14].  What are the sizes of the output arrays?  Are the output arrays 2D or 1D?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc this is the size of the output chunks 2D array

Comment: Instead of 14 columns in each row have 15 columns. Allow the first Column element (index 0) hold the arrays Row Index value from the original dataset[][] array and the other 14 hold the actual columnar elemental values. Add the 2D array chunks into a List Interface: `List<Double[][]> datasetChunks = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @DevilsHnd i'll try this thank so much

Answer (score 0):

Considering that using `List<double[][]>` is much more easier for the partitions, check the following, I have tried to put comments on some lines

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    double[][] dataset = new double[10][2];
    dataset[0][0] = 5;
    dataset[6][0] = 6;

    double[] partitions = { 0, 5, 10 }; // better if int than double, the first chunk holds elems from 0-5 of the original array, then the second 5-10....

    List<double[][]> chunks = DatasetChunks(partitions, dataset, 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < chunks.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println("chunk " + i);
      for (double[] d : chunks.get(i)) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d));
      }
    }
  }

  private static List<double[][]> DatasetChunks(double[] best, double[][] dataset, int cols) {
    List<double[][]> chunks = new ArrayList<>();
    double[][] chunk = {}; //to be initialized later
    for (int i = 0; i < best.length - 1; i++) {
      int startIndex = (int) best[i]; //needs explicit cast since the partitions array is double in the main method
      int endIndex = (int) best[i + 1];//needs explicit cast since the partitions array is double in the main method
      chunk = new double[endIndex - startIndex][cols]; // a new chunk
      for (int j = startIndex, f = 0; j < endIndex; j++, f++) {
        for (int p = 0; p < cols; p++) {
          chunk[f][p] = dataset[j][p];
        }
      }
      chunks.add(chunk);
    }
    return chunks;
  }
}
```

**output**:

```
chunk 0
[5.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0]
chunk 1
[0.0, 0.0]
[6.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: thank you so much but I've forgotten to mention that best is random indexes and each index give me a row from the dataset

Comment: No problem, but dont forget to make it `int`. you can use it like this too `int[] partitions  = { 0, 1, 8 };`

Answer (score 0):

Well 65,000 Rows with each row containing 14 Columns really isn't all that much and can be partitioned into let's say 500 Row (130) partitions pretty much instantly, even on a 10 year old computer providing the **dataset[][]** array is already contained in memory.

A simple method can partition your two dimensional double type array but into a List Interface of double[][] type (as I had mentioned within my comment):

```
List<double[][]> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
```

**The *partition2D_DoubleType_Array()* Method:**

```
/**
 * This method will partition the supplied double type 2D Array into several
 * double type 2D Arrays with each 2d Array consisting of the number Rows
 * determined by the supplied desired partition size.
 *
 * @param array                   (2D double[][] Type Array) The 2D double
 *                                type array to partition.<br>
 *
 * @param desiredSizeOfPartitions (Integer - int) The desired size for each
 *                                Array partition.<br>
 *
 * @return A List Interface of double[][] ({@code List<double[][]>})
 *         containing all the Partitioned double[][] type arrays.
 */
public static List<double[][]> partition2D_DoubleType_Array(final double[][] array, final int desiredSizeOfPartitions) {
    int desiredPartitionSize = desiredSizeOfPartitions;
    List<double[][]> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
    int numberOfArrays = (int) Math.ceil((double) array.length / desiredPartitionSize);
    int rowsNeeded = (int) Math.ceil((double) array.length / numberOfArrays);
    double[][] dataChunk = new double[rowsNeeded][array[0].length + 1];

    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        dataChunk[k][0] = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            dataChunk[k][j + 1] = array[i][j];
        }
        k++;
        if (k == rowsNeeded) {
            partitions.add(dataChunk);
            k = 0;
            dataChunk = new double[rowsNeeded][array[0].length + 1];
        }
    }
    if (k > 0) {
        partitions.add(dataChunk);
    }
    return partitions;
}
```

To use the above method you would of course require a filled 2D double type Array. I don't know how you are filling the `dataset[][]` array but for testing purposes we'll use this:

**Filling the *dataset[][]* Array for testing:**

```
double[][] dataset = new double[65000][14];
// Fill the dataset 2D Array with fictitious floating point values.
String title = "Creating a 2D double Type Array: dataset[65000][14] and "
               + "filling with fictitious data values.";
String underline = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(title.length(), "-"));
System.out.println(title);
System.out.println(underline);
for (int i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++) {
        dataset[i][j] = (double) (j + i) + (0.5d);
    }
    /* Un-comment the below line if you want to view the created
       dataset[][] array within the Console Window.   */
    // System.out.println((i + 1) + ") " + Arrays.toString(dataset[i]));
}
System.out.println("Array Creation COMPLETE!");
System.out.println();
```

Now that the **dataset[][]** array is created and filled, we can actually partition it into 130 partitions of double[][] type 2D arrays consisting of 500 Rows with each row containing **15** Columns. Wait...**15** Columns? The partitioned arrays are suppose to have **14** Columns!

We've actually made a modification to the partitioned arrays whereas we've added one additional element to each Row so that we can store the original **dataset[][]** Row Index value into the very first element of each partition array Row (at index **0**). So, from this point on, each partition array row will contain the row index value of where the data was actually acquired from within the **dataset[][]** array. We need to keep this in mind when actually retrieving all the desired columnar data from whatever partition array row.

Why is this done? For the simple reason that you have a need to deal with retrieving partitioned Row columnar data based on a **random** `dataset[][]` array Row Index value (0 to 65000). From this random Row Index value we can determine which Partition the data Row is contained in and because we stored the original Row Index values at index 0 of each partitioned array row we can acquired the exact data row within that partition so to get the needed columnar data [index 1 to index 14]. Remember, index 0 is reserved for the **original** Row Index value from the `dataset[][]` array.

**Partitioning the *dataset[][]* Array:**

```
// Partition into 130 2D Arrays [500][14]:
title = "Partitioning The dataset[][] 2D Array into 130 individual 2D "
        + "Arrays consisting of 500 Rows:";
underline = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(title.length(), "-"));
System.out.println(title);
System.out.println(underline);

int desiredPartitionSize = 500;
List<double[][]> partitions = partition2D_DoubleType_Array(dataset, desiredPartitionSize);
System.out.println("2D Array Partitioning COMPLETE!");
```

**Acquiring Partitioned array row data based on a *random* `dataset[][]` row index value:**

```
int datasetRowIndexTotal = dataset.length;
// Allow the dataset[][] array to be garbage collected 
// in order to save memory since we don't need it anymore.
dataset[0] = null;

/* Retrieve a random row index value from the original dataset[][] 
   array and locate all the columnar values for that row from within 
   the Partitioned arrays. We will do this five times therefore we'll
   be pulling out five random Row Index values determined from the 
   original dataset[][] array (total rows now in datasetRowIndexTotal.  */
for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
    // Get a random row index value
    int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random() * ((datasetRowIndexTotal) - 0)) + 0;
    System.out.println("Find data from random Row Index #: --> " + randomIndex);
    
    /* Determine which Partition Array the generated
       random row index value will be contained in.  */
    int partitionIndex = ((int) Math.ceil((double) randomIndex / desiredPartitionSize)) - 1;
    System.out.println("Determined 'Partition' Index is: --> " + partitionIndex);
    /* For readability, place the Partition Array
       into a tmp[][] double type 2D Array.   */
    double[][] tmp = partitions.get(partitionIndex);
    /* For demo simplicity we're going to place
       the acquired columnar values into a comma
       (", ") delimited String using StringBuilder.  */
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    // Iterate through the determined Partition Array.
    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        /* Is the desired Row Index value in this 
           particular Partition Array Row?     */
        if ((int)tmp[i][0] == randomIndex) {
            /* Yes...get the columnar values for this data Row. 
               Notice how we start j from 1 (not 0)? This is 
               because index 0 is reserved for original Row
               index values (remember).         */
            for (int j = 1; j < tmp[i].length; j++) {
                if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                sb.append(tmp[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    // Display the find!
    System.out.println("Columnar Data for the random Row Index of: --> " + randomIndex);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    System.out.println();
}
```

When all the code is entered correctly and you run it, you should see ***something like*** this within your Console Window:

```
Creating a 2D Double Type Array: dataset[65000][14] and filling with fictitious data values.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Array Creation COMPLETE!

Partitioning The dataset[][] 2D Array into 130 individual 2D Arrays consisting of 500 Rows:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2D Array Partitioning COMPLETE!


Find data from random Row Index #: --> 1127
Determined 'Partition' Index is: --> 2
Columnar Data for the random Row Index of: --> 1127
1127.5, 1128.5, 1129.5, 1130.5, 1131.5, 1132.5, 1133.5, 1134.5, 1135.5, 1136.5, 1137.5, 1138.5, 1139.5, 1140.5

Find data from random Row Index #: --> 1406
Determined 'Partition' Index is: --> 2
Columnar Data for the random Row Index of: --> 1406
1406.5, 1407.5, 1408.5, 1409.5, 1410.5, 1411.5, 1412.5, 1413.5, 1414.5, 1415.5, 1416.5, 1417.5, 1418.5, 1419.5

Find data from random Row Index #: --> 36801
Determined 'Partition' Index is: --> 73
Columnar Data for the random Row Index of: --> 36801
36801.5, 36802.5, 36803.5, 36804.5, 36805.5, 36806.5, 36807.5, 36808.5, 36809.5, 36810.5, 36811.5, 36812.5, 36813.5, 36814.5

Find data from random Row Index #: --> 28021
Determined 'Partition' Index is: --> 56
Columnar Data for the random Row Index of: --> 28021
28021.5, 28022.5, 28023.5, 28024.5, 28025.5, 28026.5, 28027.5, 28028.5, 28029.5, 28030.5, 28031.5, 28032.5, 28033.5, 28034.5

Find data from random Row Index #: --> 18916
Determined 'Partition' Index is: --> 37
Columnar Data for the random Row Index of: --> 18916
18916.5, 18917.5, 18918.5, 18919.5, 18920.5, 18921.5, 18922.5, 18923.5, 18924.5, 18925.5, 18926.5, 18927.5, 18928.5, 18929.5
```